# Disposing of arguments for an iterator block

Tags: c#, dispose, enumerator

Allright, here it goes a good piece of bad code:

```
public class Log : CachingProxyList<Event> {
    public static Log FromFile(String fullPath) {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
                return new Log(sr);
            }
        }
    }
    public Log(StreamReader stream)
        : base(Parser.Parse(Parser.Tokenize(stream))) {
        /* Here goes some "magic", the whole reason for this
         * class to exist, but not really relevant to the issue */
    }
}
```

And now some context into the issue:

`CachingProxyList` is an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` that provides a custom "caching" enumerator: it takes an `IEnumerable<T>` on its constructor, and initially enumerates through it, but saves each item on a private `List<T>` field so further iterations run through that before going on with the actual parsing (rather than parsing every now and again; or having to parse a huge log just to query a small portion of it).
Note that this optimization was actually *needed*, and most of it is already working (if I remove the `using` statements, everything goes fine except for the leaking file handles).

Both `Parse` and `Tokenize` are iterator blocks (AFAIK, the only sane way I could have deferred execution and clean code at the same time); their signatures are `IEnumerable<Event> Parse(IEnumerable<Token>)` and `IEnumerable<Token> Tokenize(StreamReader)`. Their logics are unrelated to the issue.

The logical flow is quite clear; and the intent of each part of the code rather obvious; but those `using` blocks don't get along with the whole deferred execution thing (by the time I'm enumerating through my `Log` object, the `using` have already been exited and the stream disposed, so `Tokenize`'s attempts to read from it miserably crash).

I can afford having a lock on the file (the open stream) for a relatively long time, but sooner or later I'll have to close it. Since I can't really use the `using`s, I'll have to explicitly dispose of the streams.

**The question is**: where should I put the calls to `Dispose()`? Is there any common idiom to deal with scenarios like these? I wouldn't like to do this the "old way" (releasing resources at several places, having to review each release anytime a tiny bit of the code changes somewhere, and so on).

My first idea was making the `Log` class disposable, so its constructor could take a file-name and have all the resource-management within the class (requiring only the consumer to dispose of the `Log` itself when done), but I can see no way of creating and saving the stream before calling the `base` constructor (the stream is required for the calls that yield the argument for that constructor).

Note: the `CachingProxyList` shouldn't be touched unless strictly needed (I want to keep it generic enough to make it reusable). Specially, the constructor is essential to enforce some invariants the rest of the implementation heavily relies in (such as the internal enumerator objects never being null). Everything else, OTOH, should be fair game.

Thanks for your patience if you have read this, and also thanks in advance for any help provided `;)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Classes that encapsulate unmanaged resources need to implement dispose pattern (`IDisposable` interface). For example stream, database connection, etc
- Every resource must have **one owner**
- Owner is responsible for calling `Dispose()` on the resource
- If owner cannot immediately call `Dispose()` on its resource or does not know when to call it, then it needs to implement `IDisposable` interface itself and call `Dispose()` on its resource in there.

Above statements could have exceptions but that is the general rule. Example is `StreamWriter` which takes in a stream (which implement `IDisposable` interface) and that forces it to implement `IDisposable` interface itself - *since it does not know when to dispose it*.

It is the same in your case. Your class uses a disposable resource while it does not know when to dispose it - *or that is what I assume*. This would make it to implement `IDisposable` interface. Client of your `Log` class will have to call `Dispose()` on your class.

So as you can see, this becomes a chain while the non-disposable client will have to call dispose on the resource it uses and that resource will dispose its resource, etc...

Comment: This was subtle, but led to a solution: it turned the issue into deciding who/what should own the streams, and I guess the `Tokenize` method is the best candidate (it's the only one who is actually using them after all). "Owner is responsible for calling Dispose() on the resource" explicitly answered the question, and "Every resource must have one owner" made the root of the issue obvious. Thanks!

Comment: A note on your edit: As I mentioned on the question, making the `Log` class disposable was my first idea, but had some issues (to pass the stream to `Tokenize`, but also save it for later disposal). The actual solution will be to pass the file name itself all the way down to `Tokenize`, so then the method will create, "own", and dispose of the streams. On a side note, I think it was a good idea to highlight the "one owner" point: it's been the whole key to solving this.

Comment: +1. herenvardo, it is OK not to have "using" around opening stream if stream (or any other similar resource) is owned by something else. Passing file name to your Log class makes it responsible for 2 things at the same time - opening file and reading log, consider actually passing stream to split responsibilities. At least consider having both flavors (check XmlWriter.Create method for possible approach).

Comment: @Alexei: Thanks for your comment, but I strongly dislike the idea of disposing of a resource from a code block that did _not_ create it. This actually playes well with the "have one owner" concept: the code creating and disposing of it will invariably be the owner. Now that you mention it, my `Log` class is actually not responsible for anything other than spreading the work among other code (caching to the base class, file I/O to the tokenizer, parsing to the parser, etc).

Comment: (continuation)  I _could_ split the `Tokenize` method (so another method takes care of actually opening, reading, and disposing of the streams, and it just splits the read data to tokens), but I'm not sure if it's worth it.