# Generic IDisposable wrapper for stream - alternative to catching all exceptions

Tags: c#, .net

So I've just written this implementation for a type that abstracts a file and implements `IDisposable` over the stream that it contains.  It is intended to be used in any project:

```
public void Dispose()
{
  if (_contentStream == null)
    return;
  lock (_contentStreamLocker)
  {
    if (_contentStream == null)
      return;

    try
    {
      _contentStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      //legitimate? - don't let any exception prevent 
      //us from successfully disposing?
    }  
    _contentStream = null;
  }
}
```

So I feel dirty, obviously, because:

- I'm catching `Exception`
- I'm doing nothing with `Exception`

But since I can't guarantee the behaviour of the underlying stream (also accounting for custom implementations) - i.e. if it's already disposed or if it's in a state where the implementation decides disposal is impossible - I can't really see what else to do.

Obviously I shouldn't be hiding bad implementations of `Stream`'s `Dispose()`; but I think there is a half-way-house here.

In particular is the fact that this object doesn't necessarily 'own' the stream, and therefore won't have to be always responsible for `Dispose()`ing.  It should therefore be tolerant to when the stream has been disposed by somebody else.

Clearly, in most cases this won't be an issue; get a file in a `using` block perhaps, read it, do something with it and then dispose of it.  But there's those edge-cases; and they bother me!

Initially I wrote it as `catch(ObjectDisposedException){ }` - but that's only an informal pattern that can't be relied upon either.

What should I do?  Keep it as this, despite the fact that exception gulping is bad karma? Gulp *only* `ObjectDisposedException`, even though that's not much better?  Or should I just not have any exception gulping or handling at all?

I can see merits in all cases; just can't figure out which of them wins.

Comment: If the stream is private to your class what would have disposed it? Is the stream publically exposed?

Comment: @Jodrell - ah good question - the Stream can be set into the object.  The class implements an interface which is get/set so that callers can fill out the file object and give it to a service, and equally retrieve a file and its stream from the service.  The environment is *heavily* abstracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, if you can't figure out which one wins, it's because there's going to be useful information that can't be handled "generically". In this case, I think it preferable to let the caller deal with it, because they'll be in a concrete situation that allows them to better judge.

How is the stream introduced to this class? If you can engineer such that it is passed in, then why not let the caller deal with its disposal and not concern yourself with it. It's always bugged me that `StreamReader` takes on this responsibility. I wouldn't much care if it didn't.

**DO NOT SWALLOW** the exception, especially in code intended for external consumption.

Comment: Swallowing object disposal exceptions and finalise exceptions are OK.

Comment: Translation: "The potential to silently leak resources and break postconditions is okay"

Answer (score 2):

As you have said, **if you do not own the disposable, then you should not dispose it**. *You should not be even temped to call Dispose.*

Have a look at my answer here.

[Disposing of arguments for an iterator block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559781/disposing-of-arguments-for-an-iterator-block/5559850#5559850)

---

## UPDATE

OK, the question of whether you own the disposable is not answered by who created the disposable. Ownership can be passed to other classes. `StreamReader` will **assume ownership** as soon as a stream is passed to it. So the creator of stream does not have to calls dispose and can rely on `StreamReader` to do it.

Comment: Because `StreamReader` will **assume** owning it. You can be passed a stream and take away the ownership.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you want to implement your dispose pattern according to the [Microsoft guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e%28VS.71%29.aspx), If the client of your wrapper has "pulled the rug" on the base stream you should let the exception get to them so they can deal with it or, at least know about it.

Comment: This is a fair point. let the caller realise they have screwed up.